# Selection Marks recognition in Forms Recognizer

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I'd like to recognize selection-marks (yes/no, [x]/[ ]) with the form-recognizer. I'm **using the labeling tool** and wondering if it's possible and if so how? The third layer of the labeling tool is named "**Selection Marks**", so this may be something which is in the works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form Recognizer does not yet support check boxes and selection Marks, this feature is coming soon stay tuned.

Neta - MSFT

Comment: Is there any ETA for this feature? We're hardly need this feature.
Maybe a alpha, beta, preview in which we can participate?

Answer (score 1):

Selection marks / Checkboxes are now available in Forms Recognizer API 2.1 https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-1/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomForm

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important details from the link provided in the answer itself. This can help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.